# IOS facebook graph api - get large picture from posts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get posts using:
https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGENAME/posts?access_token=MYTOKEN

One of the element of the result is:

> "picture": "URLOFTHEIMAGE"

`URLOFTHEIMAGE` is the URL of the small picture, I need the large one.

Is it possible? How can i get it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check, you'll also get a key: `object_id` from the api call you are doing.

Make the API call : `http://graph.facebook.com/object_id` - [Example](http://graph.facebook.com/304463359580978)

You'll get an array- `images`, fetch the image that you like.

Comment: Well, but isn’t there a way to have the graph API return the large image URL directly in the “posts” call?

Comment: No. But how does that matter? You just have to parse the simple json? PS. pls accept the answer if helped!